# Edit DNS records with gcloud by reading/piping from file

Tags: dns, gcloud, google-cloud-dns

I am able to edit DNS records with gcloud tool by interactively editing JSON file from vi/mate using the command:

```
gcloud dns records --zone=myzone edit
```

However, I would like to be able to do bulk updates, something like this:

```
gcloud dns records --zone=myzone edit < my-additional-records.txt
```

...where my-additional-records.txt contain the DNS records I want to add.

I think it is not so simple as the JSON file to edit contains both addition and deletion of DNS records. So, any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could try using the linux line editor 'ed' like this:

```
EDITOR=ed gcloud dns records --zone=myzone edit <<-EOF
12i
, {
        "kind": "dns#resourceRecordSet",
        "name": "a.mydomain.org.",
        "rrdatas": [
            "111.222.111.222"
        ],
        "ttl": 21600,
        "type": "A"
}
.
,wq
EOF
```

This assumes that the top of the edit file looks something like this (so you an append your addition to the 12th line)

```
{
    "additions": [
        {
            "kind": "dns#resourceRecordSet",
            "name": "mydomain.org.",
            "rrdatas": [
                "ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. dns-admin.google.com. 2 21600 3600 1209600 300"
            ],
            "ttl": 21600,
            "type": "SOA"
        },
```

More details on how to use ed here: http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html

Answer (score 2):

Providing this new answer since `gcloud dns ...` has been significantly improved since this question was asked. There are now two ways in which you can edit record-sets.

1. Using export/import commands as follows:

   ```
   gcloud dns record-sets export --zone my-zone RECORDS-FILE
   ```

   By default, `RECORDS-FILE` is in yaml format. You can also get it in [zone file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) by using the `--zone-file-format` flag.

   You can then edit `RECORDS-FILE` using any editor of your choice, and import the changed records using:

   ```
   gcloud dns record-sets import --zone my-zone --delete-all-existing RECORDS-FILE
   ```

   Import also accepts `--zone-file-format`. If you want to just add/edit some records but not all of them, you can omit the `--delete-all-existing` flag.
2. Using the transaction command group as follows:

   ```
   gcloud dns record-sets transaction start # Start transaction
   gcloud dns record-sets transaction add/remove # Add remove records
   gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute # Execute transaction
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that myself, but if the JSON format is the one here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/getting-started

How about just setting `deletions : []` (empty JSON array).
Wouldn't that achieve what you want (no deletions)? Is that failing somehow?

**Update 1:**

If the problem is the actual piping input to the program and you can't find a shell based way to do it, I found [this migration script](https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/migrating-bind-zone-python), that shows how you can script this action (using python).